# Search for duplicates, then assign value to another column based on which has the highest value in a separate column

Tags: mysql

I need to look for duplicates in my table, then check to see which has the highest age, update the oldest column with which one of them is the oldest, by replacing with their name.

```
+---------+-----+--------+
|  Name   | Age | Oldest |
+---------+-----+--------+
| John    | 22  | NULL   |
| John    | 25  | NULL   |
| James1  | 34  | NULL   |
+---------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Your example doesn't have any duplicates.

Comment: @The Impaler Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: Add the desired output also

Comment: @Conor But... for the first two rows it will always be `John`... or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
You will find your duplicates with this select statement
SELECT name FROM your_table
GROUP BY name
Having COUNT(name) > 1

result "John"

This will result in a list (of one in this case) of duplicate names.
```

Then you may use this update statement to obtain the result you are looking for:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET oldest = name
WHERE name = 'John'
AND age IN (SELECT MAX(age) FROM your_table WHERE name = 'John'
```

In this particular case, you need to do the process manually running the update statement once for each duplicate that you found with the duplicate select query.

In any case, it would be convenient that your table had an identification column such  an id (INT)column. This two step process may be further develop in a stored procedure.